# Orthogonal matrix with usual dot product

Tags: matrices

I know the following matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \sin(x) & x \\ 1 & \cos(x) \end{bmatrix}\quad B=\begin{bmatrix} \sin(x) & x+1 \\ -1 & \cos(x) \end{bmatrix}$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ are orthogonal with the usual dot product and I have to find the value of $x$.

I tried to make $A^{T}\cdot B=B\cdot A^{T}=Id$ but I don't think is the right way to do it cause my options for $x$ are integer numbers.

Comment: That isn't the right approach. You should treat $A$ and $B$ as two $4$-vectors and see when their dot product vanishes.

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the question. You are not asked to find the values of $x$ that make $A$ and $B$ orthogonal matrices. Instead, you are asked to find the values of $x$ such that, when $A$ and $B$ are viewed as *vectors* in the vector space $\mathbb R^{2\times2}$, the two "vectors" will be orthogonal to each other with respect to the "usual dot product", which is the dot product on $\mathbb R^4$ when you treat $A$ and $B$ as two $4$-vectors. That is, you are asked what values of $x$ would make
$$
(\sin(x),1,x,\cos(x))\cdot(\sin(x),-1,x+1,\cos(x))
$$
vanishes, so that the two vectors above are orthogonal to each other. The answer should be obvious.

This inner product above is known as *Frobenius inner product* in the literature. It is usually expressed in equivalent form as $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$.